# Problem when encrypting/decrypting by using Encrypt package

Tags: dart, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have these PostgreSQL commands:

```
select encrypt_iv('test1','테스트2','测试3','aes-cbc');
select convert_from(decrypt_iv('\x8e9a657e13b64f4111ab1668dc0f5747','테스트2','测试3','aes-cbc'),'SQL_ASCII');
```

I'm trying to reproduce those commands in Dart by using [Encrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt) package:

```
void main(List<String> args) {
  final plainText = 'test1';

  final key = Key.fromUtf8('테스트2');
  final iv = IV.fromUtf8('测试3');
  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));

  final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
  final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);

  print(decrypted);
  print(encrypted.bytes);
  print(encrypted.base16);
  print(encrypted.base64);  
}
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
Unhandled exception:
Invalid argument(s): Initialization vector must be the same length as block size
#0      CBCBlockCipher.init (package:pointycastle/block/modes/cbc.dart:52:7)
#1      PaddedBlockCipherImpl.init (package:pointycastle/padded_block_cipher/padded_block_cipher_impl.dart:47:12)
#2      AES.encrypt (package:encrypt/src/algorithms/aes.dart:35:9)
#3      Encrypter.encryptBytes (package:encrypt/src/encrypter.dart:12:19)
#4      Encrypter.encrypt (package:encrypt/src/encrypter.dart:20:12)
#5      main (file:///home/userx/Projects/dart/encrypt_example/bin/main.dart:11:31)
#6      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:281:32)
#7      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
```

Help is missing in this package so I don't know how to properly use it.

Can someone give me some guidance on its use or suggest another package for that purpose?

Answer (score 2):

> Initialization vector must be the same length as block size

AES block size is 128 bit (16 bytes), therefore

- IV must be 16 bytes long
- AES key must be 128, 192 or 256 bits long (16, 24 or 32 bytes) based on the algorithm used

The PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html#id-1.11.7.35.9) claims for IV:

> It is clipped or padded with zeroes if not exactly block size.

I assume (!) it will be the same for the key. IMHO this is a terrible idea from security and interoperability perspective), but we have to live with it. So try to have a zero-byte array of required length and copy your shorter IV or key to the array.

Next

- IV must be random and unpredictable for the cbc mode to be safe, usually stored along (next to) the cipthertext
- You may hit another issue, but basically you need to get all parameters right - aes-size, key, iv, mode of encryption

Comment: Thanks @gusto2, I'm (mis)understanding that `key` and `iv` must be fixed values, that is, `  `Key.fromLength(16)` and `IV.fromLength(16)` respectively. Anyway, returning to the initial case, how would you properly translate `select encrypt_iv('test1','테스트2','测试3','aes-cbc')` into Dart language by using Encrypt package?

Comment: @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα I understand the encryption conditions, I'm not any dart expert. Encryption works on byte arrays, so the question is how your parameters are converted to a byte array. UTF-8 encoding? Other? I just pointed out where you have an issue and what you need to achieve. The rest is up to you. And IV should be randomly generated for encyption, not static.

Comment: Thanks @gusto2 again, I'll give it some thought over again.